# how to match a user against postfix virtual maps using regex?

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I have a postfix running , which recieve normal emails abc@example.com and it also recieve emails from bounce+abc@exmaple.com.

using virtual alias maps i can do simple routing like

```
@example.com abc
```

But how to write a regex that when email is recieved from bounce, it saves the email to bounce user? but if its normal email then it saves to other account?

like this

```
/bounce\+.*@example.com    bounce
@example.com               abc
```

what would be right regex to match the bounce user?

one of the production user email address is :

bouncer+george.tawiah=motc.com@gprodwoo.com

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes " warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/v2, line 1: ignoring unrecognized request"

Comment: and "no closing regexp delimiter "@": skipping this rule"

Comment: `/bounce\+.*@example\.com$/    bounce`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your regex to this one:

```
/^bounce\+.*@example.com$/ bounce
```

Edit:

Catch all other users:

```
/^.*@example.com$/ other
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. and how to match all other users?

Comment: @Farhan, please check my edited answer.

Comment: @Farhan With recipient_delimiter set to `+` regex map use should be unnecessary in most situations.

Comment: Thanks, but does the order matters? as the email is still going to "other"

Comment: Try changing the other line to just: "@example.com other" - without a regex. Per your question, yes the order is from the first rule to last rule, the first one caught which matches a rule takes action.

Comment: i got " line 2: no closing regexp delimiter "@": skipping this rule"

Comment: now i tried "/@example.com/" no error, but it does not catches all other emails

Comment: No it won't work, remove the "/ /" and place the @example.com line first in the file and retry

Comment: when there is "regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual then it will always look for regular expression only, normal one give error always

Comment: Ok, so you should add the catch-all rule in another file and add it to the main.cf file, want to try and update me?

Comment: there can only be one virtual maps file.

Comment: @Farhan, Please check this url: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html and go to topic "Solution 2: Postfix version 2.1 and earlier"

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured [recipient_delimiter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) as `+`? (default: empty)
According [virtual](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) documentation it should fix your problem.

`man virtual` [virtual - Postfix virtual alias table format](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html)

> **ADDRESS EXTENSION**
>          When a mail address localpart contains the optional recipient delimiter
>          (e.g.,  user+foo@domain),  the  lookup  order becomes: user+foo@domain,
>          user@domain, user+foo, user, and @domain.
>          The  [propagate_unmatched_extensions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#propagate_unmatched_extensions)  parameter  controls   whether   an
>          unmatched address extension (+foo) is propagated to the result of table
>          lookup

Comment: yes, i already have set it

Comment: but how to match the word before the "+" ?

Comment: "(e.g., **user+foo@domain**), the lookup order becomes: user+foo@domain, **user@domain** "

Comment: thanks, i have both rules with me, but when add both together, then only 2nd one is triggered ( like even the bounce+@.... goto other user)

Comment: Can we set precedence?

Comment: postfix will conduct chain of four lookups for plussed email address (address with recipient_delimiter) in virtual map. First successful lookup provides the final answer. *[Sorry, it is obvious for me. I can (hardly) remember time when it had been black magic (in preceding sendmail implementation)]*